# Access data and method in devtools with Vue 3 and script setup

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, vuejs3

I wrote a component like this one:

```html
<template>
 <div>{{ myData }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
const myData = ref('')
const myFunction = () => {
  console.log('test function')
}
</script>
```

In the devtools console, how to access `myData` or `myFunction` with `$vm`?

Answer (score 3):

By dint of searching, I found!

`$vm.setupState` expose data and methods.

Comment: doesn't work for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @leachim You should select a component in the Vue devtools panel. `$vm` target the root component, and `$vm0` target the selected component.

Comment: With vue v 3.3.4 ti seams that setupState is empty. How to get the ref informations ?